# I keep getting shown "double free or corruption (out)" in my reading program and I'm not sure what it means

Tags: c, cs50

I'm writing a program where as input it takes in text and as output it prints the reading level of the text using the number of letters, sentences, and words. It then takes these amounts and finds the averages of letters per 100 words, and sentences per 100 words. Finally, the averages will be put through the Coleman-Liau index and will take the result and print the correct grade level. It does all of this fine, but I have a problem where I keep getting shown "double free or corruption (out)" and I don't know what it means.
I'm new to coding so it is hard for me to identify where the problem is, but...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{

    float l = 0;
    float s = 0;
    float w = 0;
    int o = 2;

    string t = get_string("Text: ");

    t[-1] = (char)32;

    for(int i = -1;t[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(t[i] >= (char)65 && t[i] <= (char)90)
        {
            l++;
            if (o == 1)
            {
                w++;
                o = 2;
            }
        }
        else if(t[i] >= (char)97 && t[i] <= (char)122)
        {
            l++;
            if (o == 1)
            {
                w++;
                o = 1;
            }
        }
        else if(t[i] == '.' || t[i] == '!' || t[i] == '?')
        {
            s++;
        }
        else if(t[i] == (char)32)
        {
            o = 1;
        }
    }
```

> ...I think the problem started here (I could be wrong)

```
    float L = (l / w) * 100;
    float S = (s / w) * 100;
    float index = 0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8;
    index = round(index);
    if(index >=1 && index <= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade %i", (int)index);
    }
    else if(index < 1)
    {
        printf("Below Grade 1");
    }
    else if(index > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The line where you assign to `t[-1]` is suspicious; normally you can only assign to zero or positive indices. With a negative index, you're overwriting memory that is used for book-keeping purposes.

Comment: Use 'A' rather than 65.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is:

```
t[-1] = (char)32;
```

You are writing *before* the `malloc` string returned by `get_string`. So, you are scribbling on the internal/hidden meta data that the heap uses to keep track of allocations.

Why are you using negative indexes [at all]?

Comment: Thank you Craig Estey! It's gone! The whole reason I was using negative indexes was to keep the word count accurate by changing the negative first char to a space which would then cause the first letter of a word to be looked for. I'm not sure why I didn't think of this sooner but now before the loop starts it is ready to look for the first letter of a word.